# Scripting Engine development for newbies

Tags: ironpython

I am developing an ASP.NET application that takes stock price historical data from an external data source like Yahoo.

I'd like users to be able to customize the application to provide rules on how to get the system to flag dates for entering and exiting trades, and then the application will be able to simulate the success rate of their rules.

I am new to the concept of scripting engines. I have read that IronPython is typically used for this, but I don't know how to structure my application to do this, and would like to get some guidance on where I can read more about how to do this, or even find an open-source reference implementation that is best. There are so many technology / implementation options out there, and I simply don't know how to pick the best one for the need I have in mind.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something here...

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/embedding_ironpython.shtml

I'll give it a whirl.